# Create a Powershell shortcut with start in path

Tags: powershell

Sorry if this has been asked before but I can't find a relevant answer

I want to create a shortcut on a users desktop and fill in the Start In value on in.

I can create the Icon but how do I make powershell fill in the Start in value

```
$TargetFile = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Program"
$ShortcutFile = "$env:Public\Desktop\Shorcut.lnk"
$WScriptShell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell
$Shortcut = $WScriptShell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutFile)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = $TargetFile
$Shortcut.Save()
```

Comment: Probably obvious if you run `$Shortcut | Get-Member`.

Comment: These are the options I get:

**Load**
**Save**
**Arguments**
**Description**
**FullName**
**Hotkey**
**IconLocation**
**RelativePath**
**TargetPath**
**WindowStyle**
**WorkingDirectory**

What should I use

Comment: WorkingDirectory

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ae0a4aee.aspx).

Comment: Worked thanks so much for your help people

Answer (score 5):

You can fill in the "Start in" value by simply adding this line:

```
$Shortcut.WorkingDirectory = "Path"
```